# Is if else faster than if + default?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, optimization

I conducted a simple experiment, to compare if-else to only an if (with default values preset). Example:

```
void test0(char c, int *x) {
    *x = 0;
    if (c == 99) {
        *x = 15;
    }
}

void test1(char c, int *x) {
    if (c == 99) {
        *x = 15;
    } else {
        *x = 0;
    }
}
```

For the functions above, I got the exact same assembly code (using `cmovne`).

However when adding an extra variable:

```
void test2(char c, int *x, int *y) {
    *x = 0;
    *y = 0;
    if (c == 99) {
        *x = 15;
        *y = 21;
    }
}

void test3(char c, int *x, int *y) {
    if (c == 99) {
        *x = 15;
        *y = 21;
    } else {
        *x = 0;
        *y = 0;
    }
}
```

The assembly suddenly becomes different:

```
test2(char, int*, int*):
        cmp     dil, 99
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 0
        je      .L10
        rep ret
.L10:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 15
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 21
        ret
test3(char, int*, int*):
        cmp     dil, 99
        je      .L14
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 0
        ret
.L14:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 15
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 21
        ret
```

It seems that the only difference is if the top `mov`s are done before or after the `je`.

Now (sorry my assembly is a bit crude), isn't it always better to have the `mov`s after the jump, in order to save pipeline flushes? And if so why wouldn't the optimizer (gcc6.2 -O3) use the better method?

Comment: I predict a lot of upvotes on that question :)

Comment: If you wonder whether X is faster than Y, you should profile, _profile_ and __profile__. Only accurate timings will shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Are you asking if one is faster than the other (the profile) or why the assembly is different?

Comment: The reason may be because the two pointers may point to the same object. If it's a memory-mapped output register for instance, the two pieces of code will have drastically different outcomes.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry I don't get it :(

Comment: @StoryTeller: they're not `volatile`, so the compiler is allowed to assume that it doesn't have to do the `*x = 0` store if `c==99`.  The code difference is due to the compiler implementing the code literally, for lack of any other hints.  With profile-guided optimization, it would know how likely the if() condition was to be taken/not-taken and lay out the code accordingly so the most common case was the fast path.  ([Or with `likely`/`unlikely` macros using GNU C `__builtin_expect()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301397/likelyx-and-builtin-expectx-1))

Comment: @PeterCordes - And yet the chance at aliasing still makes optimization logic a sticky matter. In `C` I presume the above would yield the exact same code if the two pointers were marked with `restrict`

Comment: At any rate, if default isn't hard I think default+if more better then if/else.

Comment: @StoryTeller: yes, potential aliasing means the compiler needs to do that last set of stores in program order.  But both branches store through both pointers, so it doesn't really reduce the optimization possibilities.  If there were two levels of indirection, where the first store could change the destination of the second store, that would be another matter.  But since `*x` can't alias `y`, only `*y`, I agree that adding `restrict` probably won't matter, in practice or in theory.

Comment: The alignment of the branching addresses may make a difference in the execution time, so it is virtually impossible to draw a general conclusion.

Comment: The optimizer will align the branch targets as necessary for performance (on x86, that is generally 16-byte alignment), so it's reasonable to assume that alignment is *not* an issue here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For the functions above, I got the exact same assembly code (using cmovne).

Sure, some compilers may make that optimization, but it is not guaranteed. It is very possible that you will get different object code for those two ways of writing the function.

In fact, *no* optimization is guaranteed (although modern optimizing compilers do an impressive job most of the time), so you should either write the code to capture the semantic meaning you intend for it to have, *or* you should verify the generated object code and write the code to ensure that you are getting the expected output.

Here is what older versions of MSVC will generate when targeting x86-32 (primarily [because they don't know to use the CMOV instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661285/generating-cmov-instructions-using-microsoft-compilers/41144749#41144749)):

```
test0 PROC
    cmp      BYTE PTR [c], 99
    mov      eax, DWORD PTR [x]
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax], 0
    jne      SHORT LN2
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax], 15
LN2:
    ret      0
test0 ENDP
```

```
test1 PROC
    mov      eax, DWORD PTR [x]
    xor      ecx, ecx
    cmp      BYTE PTR [c], 99
    setne    cl
    dec      ecx
    and      ecx, 15
    mov      DWORD PTR [eax], ecx
    ret      0
test1 ENDP
```

Note that `test1` gives you branchless code that utilizes the `SETNE` instruction (a conditional set, which will set its operand to 0 or 1 based on the condition code—in this case, `NE`) in conjunction with some bit-manipulation to produce the correct value. `test0` uses a conditional branch to skip over the assignment of 15 to `*x`.

The reason this is interesting is because it is almost exactly the *opposite* of what you might expect. Naïvely, one might expect that `test0` would be the way you'd hold the optimizer's hand and get it to generate branchless code. At least, that's the first thought that went through my head. But in fact, that is not the case! The optimizer is able to recognize the `if`/`else` idiom and optimize accordingly! It is not able to make that same optimization in the case of `test0`, where you tried to outsmart it.

> However when adding an extra variable ... The assembly suddenly becomes different

Well, no surprise there. A small change in the code can often have a significant effect on the emitted code. Optimizers are not magic; they are just really complex pattern matchers. You changed the pattern!

Granted, an optimizing compiler *could* have used two conditional moves here to generate branchless code. In fact, that is precisely what Clang 3.9 does for `test3` (but not for `test2`, consistent with our above analysis showing that optimizers may be better able to recognize standard patterns than unusual ones). But GCC doesn't do this. Again, there is no guarantee of a particular optimization being performed.

> It seems that the only difference is if the top "mov"s are done before or after the "je".
>
> Now (sorry my assembly is a bit crude), isn't it always better to have the movs after the jump, in order to save pipeline flushes?

No, not really. That would not improve the code in this case. If the branch is mispredicted, you're going to have a pipeline flush no matter what. It doesn't much matter whether the speculatively mispredicted code is a `ret` instruction or if it is a `mov` instruction.

The only reason it would matter that a `ret` instruction immediately followed a conditional branch is if you were writing the assembly code by hand and didn't know to use a `rep ret` instruction. This is [a trick necessary for certain AMD processors that avoids a branch-prediction penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526361/what-does-rep-ret-mean). Unless you were an assembly guru, you probably wouldn't have known this trick. But the compiler does, and also knows it is not necessary when you're specifically targeting an Intel processor or different generation of AMD processor that doesn't have this quirk.

However, you might be right about it being better to have the `mov`s after the branch, but not for the reason you suggested. Modern processors (I believe this is Nehalem and later, but I'd look it up in [Agner Fog's excellent optimization guides](http://www.agner.org/optimize) if I needed to verify) are capable of macro-op fusion under certain circumstances. Basically, macro-op fusion means that the CPU's decoder will combine two eligible instructions into one micro-op, saving bandwidth at all stages of the pipeline. A `cmp` or `test` instruction followed by a conditional branch instruction, as you see in `test3`, is eligible for macro-op fusion (actually, there are other conditions that must be met, but this code does meet those requirements). Scheduling other instructions in between the `cmp` and `je`, as you see in `test2`, makes macro-op fusion impossible, potentially making the code execute more slowly.

Arguably, though, this is an optimization defect in the compiler. It *could* have reordered the `mov` instructions to place the `je` immediately after the `cmp`, preserving the ability for macro-op fusion:

```
test2a(char, int*, int*):
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 0    ; do the default initialization *first*
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 0
    cmp     dil, 99               ; this is now followed immediately by the conditional
    je      .L10                  ;  branch, making macro-op fusion possible
    rep ret
.L10:
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 15
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 21
    ret
```

Another difference between the object code for `test2` and `test3` is code size. Thanks to padding that is emitted by the optimizer to align the branch target, the code for `test3` is 4 bytes larger than `test2`. Very unlikely that is enough difference to matter, though, especially if this code is not being executed within a tight loop where it is guaranteed to be hot in the cache.

So, does that mean you should always write the code as you did in `test2`?
Well, no, for several reasons:

1. As we have seen, it *might* be a pessimization, since the optimizer may not recognize the pattern.
2. You should write code for readability and semantic correctness *first*, only going back to optimize it when your profiler indicates that it is actually a bottleneck. And then, you should only optimize after inspecting and verifying the object code emitted by your compiler, otherwise you could end up with a pessimization. (The standard "trust your compiler until proven otherwise" advice.)
3. Even though it may be optimal in certain very simple cases, the "preset" idiom is not generalizable. If your initialization is time-consuming, it may be faster to skip over it when possible. (There is one example discussed [here, in the context of VB 6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149900/format-rgb-long-as-hex-string-in-vb6/150074#150074), where string-manipulation is so slow that eliding it when possible actually results in faster execution time than fancy branchless code. More generally, the same rationale would apply if you were able to branch around a function call.)

   Even here, where it appears to result in very simple and possibly more optimal code, it may actually be slower because you are writing to memory *twice* in the case where `c` is equal to 99, and saving nothing in the case where `c` is *not* equal to 99.

   You might save this cost by rewriting the code such that it accumulates the final value in a temporary register, only storing it to memory at the end, *e.g.*:

   ```
   test2b(char, int*, int*):
       xor     eax, eax               ; pre-zero the EAX register
       xor     ecx, ecx               ; pre-zero the ECX register
       cmp     dil, 99
       je      Done
       mov     eax, 15                ; change the value in EAX if necessary
       mov     ecx, 21                ; change the value in ECX if necessary
   Done:
       mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax   ; store our final temp values to memory
       mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], ecx
       ret
   ```

   but this clobbers two additional registers (`eax` and `ecx`) and may not actually be faster. You'd have to benchmark it. Or trust the compiler to emit this code when it is actually optimal, such as when it has inlined a function like `test2` within a tight loop.
4. Even if you could guarantee that writing the code in a certain way would cause the compiler to emit branchless code, this would not necessarily be faster! While branches are slow when they are mispredicted, mispredictions are actually quite rare. Modern processors have *extremely* good branch prediction engines, achieving prediction accuracies of greater than 99% in most cases.

   Conditional moves are great for avoiding branch mispredictions, but they have the important disadvantage of increasing the length of a dependency chain. By contrast, a correctly predicted branch *breaks* the dependency chain. (This is probably why GCC doesn't emit two CMOV instructions when you add the extra variable.) A conditional move is only a performance win if you *expect* branch prediction to fail. If you can count on a prediction success rate of ~75% or better, a conditional branch is probably faster, because it breaks the dependency chain and has a lower latency. And I would suspect that would be the case here, unless `c` alternates rapidly back and forth between 99 and not-99 each time the function is called. (See [Agner Fog's "Optimizing subroutines in assembly language"](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf), pp 70–71.)

Comment: Wow. Thanks and thanks again for the Great links to Agner Fog.

Comment: Nice answer that covers what compilers really do with code like this.  I think in the general case, I'd recommend writing code that writes to a variable exactly once, rather than at least once and sometimes twice.  It seems compilers sometimes have trouble optimizing away the first store in cases where the second store happens.  It's also less likely to cause aliasing problems for the optimizer.  (Of course, hardware is usually very good at soaking this up in the store buffer and L1 cache throughput.  A second store to the same location is extremely cheap.)